# How can I debug dll if loaded in advance using visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on one wpf application. I am loading all dlls in advance in BootLoader method. when I put breakpoint inside one of my dll. I cannot debug, My breakpoints did not hit and breakpoint does not seems to be disable too.

All options are correct. Even modules tab shows symbols loaded and assembly's pdb file is in same location

[image]

```
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly> _libs;
           public App()
           {
                _libs = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>();
                BootLoader();
           }
 private void BootLoader()
        {
            Assembly a;
            foreach (var dll in new DirectoryInfo(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\..\..\").GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (!_libs.TryGetValue(dll.Name, out a))
                {
                    if (!_libs.TryAdd(dll.Name, Assembly.LoadFile(dll.FullName)))
                    {
                        Logger.Error($"CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve: could not add {dll.Name} in assembly list");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please Assist.

Comment: Can you please clarify " I cannot debug."?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: updated the question. My breakpoint does not hit and they are enable also

Comment: Where do you actually call code within the dll. Loading doesnt execute it.

Comment: What is your entry point into assembly. You dont show any code that executes a method or instantiates a type within a dynamic assembly. Loading the dll isnt enough.

Comment: @codenheim: thanks for the hint. Problem was in loading the dll.

Comment: @vishal, how did you load the dll file in your WPF app? Do you add it as the project reference in the same solution? Please visit the debug output window, maybe you could get much more information, please also make sure that the WPF app and the class library use the same .NET Framework version, and set copy local=true if you add it as the dll file reference, and make sure that the pdb and dll file was really copied to the WPF output bin\debug folder in your side.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure each assembly's pdb file is in same location.

Answer (score 0):

When we start debug our application in Visual Studio, Visual Studio will try load all assembly symbol files before all breakpoints hit. So you problem is not related to the Symbol files loading.

Please make sure you are in **Debug mode**, not in Release mode when you start debugging first.
And according to the sample code you provided, there has any condition in the BootLoader() method. Please make sure the breakpoint you added is **satisfied with the If condition statement** or out of the condition statement block.